# Branch IO - Parse one BranchUniversalObject custom metadata in 2 different apps

Tags: android, ios, branch.io

I'm struggling with an unpopular scenario that I have 2 different apps A & B, Branch Deep Link was integrated into both. Now, when I share contents from A or B, user taps on the link then:

1. if only one app installed, open it.
2. if both installed, open A.
3. BranchUniversalObject custom metadata can be parsed successfully and redirect to the destination in both apps.

I have read Branch Docs and googled a lot but haven't found any solution that perfectly fits this scenario. 
Is there any idea to get through this struggle? Or any link to prove that it's impossible.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Andy, can you add some code to your question? Right now it's hard for me to understand your question :)

Comment: Hi Tom, basically, I'm following this [docs](https://docs.branch.io/viral/content-sharing/#generate-shareable-links) to generate a shareable link with custom metadata from app A or B. All I need is pressing on this link can open one of apps A or B depends on which installed on the device, and we can parse BranchUniversalObject from this link to get the custom metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You can tie only one URI scheme to one Branch account(app) so the scenario you described is not feasible. I’d recommend creating two different apps.

Comment: it means that 1 deep link cannot work for 2 apps definitely, right? We have 2 apps associated with each other, so we would like to make any generated Deep Link from A or B be able to work on both apps, any hope for this scenario?